# Java Fine Grained Locking Linked List

Tags: java

So i've been trying to implement a fine grained and course grained locking linked list in Java. Managed to implement the course grained one like this:

[Node and setlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pska.jpg)

[Course grain implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCekM.jpg)

But i am having difficulties in completing the Fine grained one, if I follow these steps maarked in blue: 
 [Fine grain implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gO3O.jpg), i get an error saying the lock function cannot be resolved. I understand that it requires a Lock object to work with, but i do not understand how others managed to make it work.

For clarity, here's my WIP project: https://github.com/KrisTi969/PPDLab4/tree/master/src/com/company

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try to put precisely which part of code in the post you didn't understand ;-)

Comment: I am unable to use the lock function on the head, pred, or curr Nodes.I can only use it on variables declared as Lock.